# Validation, not self

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5.14 and created a request or validation with `php artisan make:request CreateInviteRequest`.

I want the user to not be able to invite themselves.

Is there a way to give a proper error saying "cannot be self"?

Right now I accomplished this with `'not_in:'.Auth::guard('api')->user()->id` like this:

```
public function rules(Request $request)
{
    return [
        'invite_user' => ['numeric', 'exists:users,id', 'not_in:'.Auth::guard('api')->user()->id]
    ];
}
```

This gives error message `The selected invite_user is invalid.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define messages

```
public function messages()
{
   return [
     'invite_user.not_in' => 'cannot be self',
   ];
}
```

Comment: Holy heck this is cool, I just added this to my CreateInviteRequest.php file and it worked!! How about for `invite_user.exists:users,id` I'm not able to add a custom rule for this.

Comment: @Blagoh add to array like `fieldName.ruleName=>'some message'`

Comment: but doing `'invite_user.exists:users,id'=>'blah'` is not working. It works if I remove the `users,id` part, but what if I have multiple `exists`?

Answer (score 1):

You can add ID to ignore as third parameter to the `exists()` rule:

```
'invite_user' => 'numeric|exists:users,id,' . auth()->id(),
```

Comment: Oh wow this is cool! How do you get the `auth()` variable in the request file?

Comment: Oh wow thank you sir!! I had done `use Auth` at top I had no idea! Also I pass `Request $request` as first arg to `rules` is this acceptable? It seems to work but I gussed at this and I have no idea why it works.

Comment: Also my sincerest thanks sir for your up votes, (im guessing it was you), because without your up votes I can't keep asking questions and I am struggling mightily :( Sincerest thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

u can achieve this by Not In.

```
public function rules(Request $request)
{
return [
    'invite_user' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
     Rule::notIn([Auth::guard('api')->user()->id]),
  ];
}
```